# Batch file won't open a hidden .vbs file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file which makes a .vbs file and is then supposed to open it. They are both in the same folder. I've tried using `start`, but it simply doesn't work for some reason. I also tried `cscript`, but since the script is supposed to be hidden, this doesn't work either. If I try to run the vbs file by hand, it works.

code:

```
@echo off
tasklist | find "wscript.exe" >nul: && goto runningalr

:reset
type nul > sound.vbs
(echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^))>>sound.vbs

:begin
set /p loop=Do you want the music to repeat? (y/n) ... 
if /i %loop%==y goto repeat
if /i %loop%==n goto begin1
goto begin

:repeat
(echo do until false)>>sound.vbs
goto begin1

:begin1
set /p damd=The music's directory? (type "exit" if no more) ... 
if /i %damd%==exit goto start
( echo Sound.URL = "%damd%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000)>>sound.vbs
goto begin1

:runningalr
set /p kill=Music already playing. Do you want to stop it? (y/n) ... 
if %kill%==y taskkill /f /im wscript.exe && exit
if %kill%==n goto gonnaexit

:gonnaexit
<nul set /p "=Press any key to exit ... "
pause >nul
exit

:start
if /i %loop%==y (echo loop)>>sound.vbs
start C:\Users\User\Desktop\server\sound.vbs
```

Why didn't `start` work for me and what works?

Comment: Try with absolute paths. Hidden scripts should be executed normally just as visible ones.

Comment: @aschipfl Already tried that, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: How many comments are you hoping for before you bother providing the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Compo Excuse me, but i'm new to this.

Comment: @Compo Instead of critizing people just because they are new to stack overflow and that they haven't included their code in their question, please just ask for them to add it. No need to possibly start an argument. I am not a moderator and I cant force you to do this, but there is a high chance that moderators may warn and/or ban your account. You also will most likely gain alot of hate and also be unrespected amongst the community. Treat others like you want to be treated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having just "find wscript" try using "find %WINDIR%/System32/wscript.exe /I"

You might also need to run the script as an administrator, however this is unlikely.

Comment: Ah yes I knew I was missing the /I but I couldn't think of it at the time. I'll add that to it. Thank you very much for reminding me.

Comment: @J03L Oh, no.. that part at the top is just for checking if it's already running. Running as admin also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Kappa, I have an idea. What is the EXACT path to the vbs file? (Including your users username)

Comment: @Kappa oh and also, you should have the ":"s in the goto commands. It works better if you put them in (eg: goto :start)

Comment: @J03L C:\Users\User\Desktop\server\sound.vbs

Answer (score 0):

you give a dedicated path with `start`, but you write the vbs script to the current working directory. The following line starts from that working directory:

```
start "" "%~dp0sound.vbs"
```